# Java using hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

i was trying a basic program in java using hibernate... but im getting the following error description

```
WARN: HHH000277: Could not bind factory to JNDI
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [hiber]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.bind(JndiServiceImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory(SessionFactoryRegistry.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at manageEmployee.main(manageEmployee.java:26)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 6 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction cannot be cast to javax.transaction.Transaction
    at manageEmployee.addEmployee(manageEmployee.java:44)
    at manageEmployee.main(manageEmployee.java:34)
```

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this by removing the name attribute from opening session factory tag in my hibernate configuration file so that it looks like the following:

```
<session-factory>
```

instead of

```
<session-factory name="">
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your imports statement if found this:

```
import javax.transaction.Transaction;
```

Then replace this with:

```
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
```

And remove casting from all places find where you're casting like below:

```
 tx = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
```

Remove

> (Transaction)

to remove casting from all places.

Answer (score 0):

This could be triggert by either there are some depending libarys of hibernate missing or u have imported some false libarys with the same name.